# JAVASCRIPT: regex find characters between multiple | |

Tags: javascript, regex, split

how can I match all characters between 2 characters ( | | ) , such as

INPUT:

```
|one|two|three|
```

OUTPUT:

```
'one','two','three'.
```

Comment: Can you show part of your script such like the function?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expression:

```
> '|one|two|three|'.split('|')
["", "one", "two", "three", ""]
> '|one|two|three|'.split('|').slice(1, -1)
["one", "two", "three"]
```

Comment: @Bugboy1028, This is Javascript code. Why do you think this is Python code ? Python list object does not have `slice` method.

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript regex you could try something like,

```
var text = "|one|two|three|";
var r = new RegExp("(\\|)?([\\w]*)(?=\\|)","g");
var res=r.exec(text);
while(res&&res[2]){
  console.log(res[2]);
  res=r.exec(text);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gMuDy/